# Is it possible to set stroke weight to be exactly 1 pixel in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pixel

The grid unit is 1 pixel.

Below is two overlapped rectangles:

[image: artboard screenshot]

Underlying one has blue fill color an black outline color. Also it has `Align Stroke to Inside` setting:

[image: settings screenshot]

As you see, it also has stroke weight set to 1px.

Nevertheless, the overlapping rectangle, which has no outline and blue fill is obviously slightly bigger.

Also, according to the grid, it is evident, the outline of the underlying rectangle is thicker than 1 px.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sure, but if you snap to the pixel grid then you stroke will smear over 2 pixels. You should snap to a 1/2 pixel grid instead.

Comment: what is the size of your document ?

Comment: I can not replicate this issue in CC2017 [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcs9P.jpg) nor in CS6 [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkHYg.jpg). I'm left to believe there is some setting which was overlooked, such as snap to pixel or snap to point..

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the desired result by making sure that you have de-selected the option for aligning all objects to pixel grid in the document setup.

[image: Illustrator Screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

From your image I'd suggest the rectangle *with* the black stroke isn't actually smaller, it just appears that way because of the black stroke.